# Duplicate Primary Key when Generating Data with Talend

Tags: duplicates, unique, primary-key, talend, random-data

I'm creating a job in Talend where I have to generate files containing data generated with tRowGenerator along with other sources : SQL Server database and delimited files.

[image]

The issue is that I have duplicated files with the same primary key.
All i want to get is 100 records(420 rows) :
For each Random UUID generated i shall get 42 rows and so on, but instead i'm getting the same row 10 times(it's duplicated 10 times)

[image]

I'm getting data from 3 sources as shown below:
[image]

To get this fields in my output file:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're using one of the functions in `tRowGenerator` to get random data.
The problem is that the data generation functions available from Talend are not really random, they get their values from a predefined list of values. You can look at the source code to verify that they have a hundred or so value, so you're bound to get duplicates.
To get unique values create a Talend routine with a simple method that generates a UUID:

```
public class Utils {

    /**
     * getRandom: return a random UUID
     * 
     * 
     * {talendTypes} String
     * 
     * {Category} User Defined
     * 
     * {param} string("world") input: dummy input
     * 
     * {example} getRandom("world") # 01e98b98-05d6-427c-978d-1f86d0ea4712
     */
    public static String getRandom(String input) {
        return java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

You can then access this function from `tRowGenerator`:
[image]

[image]

One more thing, I'm not sure what exactly is your requirement, but since you don't have a join key between your inputs, you get are getting a cartesian join between all your inputs (42x298x206 rows). So you might want to define a join condition.
If you do define a join condition, make sure the `tMap` inputs are in the right order (you are using the `tRowGenerator` flow as a main connection, and others as lookup).

Comment: Thx for your feedback, i really appreciate it.For the Random Data , i'm already using the function you mentioned to get random UUID, but my problem is more aboout not finding a way to join my 3 data sources, because they have nothing in common.

Comment: Ok, could you share some more detail about your input and your expected output?

Comment: I have 3 input sources : delimited file, tRowGenerator and SQL Server DB as shown in the pictures above, and i'm expecting to populate a csv file out of them.

Comment: Yes that part was clear enough :) I meant posting some sample input data, and how it should be joined, and your expected output

Comment: Yes, check my question above, i edited it by posting pictures of the input and output attributes, or do you mean data?

Comment: Sample data would be great :)

Comment: I hope the picture containing sample data is clear :|